# Is rejecting a Promise only for error cases?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this function authenticate that returns a promise. The promise then resolves with the result. False and true are expected outcomes, as I see it, and rejections should only occur in an error case. Or, is a failure in authentication considered something you would reject a promise for?

Comment: If authentication failed, you should `reject` and not return false, but if you are expecting the value to be a `Bool`, then you _were_ successful and you should resolve with the Bool regardless of the value. Promises are sort of proxies for values - they store the returned value, so only if the value could not be obtained should you `reject`. Otherwise you should `resolve`.

Comment: This is a good question. It touches on one of the failures of the promise design. There are two types of errors, expected failures, such as when a user provides bad input (such as failing to log in), and unexpected failures, which are bugs in code. The promise design merges the two concepts into a single flow making it difficult to distinguish the two for handling.

Comment: I'd say that *resolving* means using the response and continuing your application, while *rejecting* means canceling the current operation (and possibly try again or do something else).

Comment: another way to think about it - if this were a synchronous method call, would you treat regular authentication failure (bad username/password) as returning `false` or as throwing an exception?

Comment: The [Fetch API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) is a good example of this. It always triggers `then` when the server responds - even if an error code is returned - and you must check the `response.ok`. The `catch` handler is only triggered for *unexpected* errors.

Comment: I would reject in that case. Reject will propagate the rejection and bypass execution of any 'then' chains attached to that promise which handle success. For authentication failure, I'd want to make sure that nobody tries to continuation off of that and do something it shouldn't. [Be careful about how you implement reject handlers though](https://jsfiddle.net/bLyqdxtw/).

Answer (score 25):

Good question! There is no hard answer. It depends on what you consider to be *exceptional* at *that specific point of the flow*.

Rejecting a `Promise` is the same a raising an exception. Not all undesired results are *exceptional*, the result of *errors*. You could argue your case both ways:

1. Failed authentication should `reject` the `Promise`, because the caller is expecting a `User` object in return, and anything else is an exception to this flow.
2. Failed authentication should `resolve` the `Promise`, albeit to `null`, since providing the wrong credentials is not really an *exceptional* case, and the caller should not expect the flow to always result in a `User`.

Note that I'm looking at the issue **from the caller's side**. In the flow of information, does the caller *expect* his actions to result in a `User` (and anything else is an error), or does it make sense for this particular caller to handle other results?

In a multi-layered system, the answer may change as the data flows through the layers. For example:

- HTTP layer says RESOLVE! The request was sent, the socket closed cleanly, and the server emitted a valid response. The [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) does this.
- Protocol layer then says REJECT! The status code in the response was 401, which is ok for HTTP, but not for the protocol!
- Authentication layer says NO, RESOLVE! It catches the error, since 401 is the expected status for a wrong password, and resolves to a `null` user.
- Interface controller says NONE OF THAT, REJECT! The modal showing on screen was expecting a username and an avatar, and anything other than that information is an error at this point.

This 4-point example is obviously complicated, but it illustrates 2 points:

1. **Whether something is an exception/rejection or not depends on the surrounding flow and the expectations**
2. **Different layers of your program may treat the same result differently, as they are located in varying stages of the flow**

So again, no hard answer. Time to think and design!

Comment: That 4-point example is excellent! Thank you for your insightful answer.

Answer (score 6):

So Promises have a nice property that they bring JS from functional languages, which is that they indeed implement this `Either` type-constructor that glues together two other types, the `Left` type and the `Right` type, by forcing the logic to either take the one branch or the other branch.

```hs
data Either x y = Left x | Right y
```

Now you're noticing indeed that the type on the left-hand-side is ambiguous for promises; you can reject with anything. This is *true* because JS is weakly typed, but you *want to be cautious* if you're programming defensively.

The reason is that JS will take `throw` statements from promise-handling code and bundle it up into the `Left` side of that too. Technically in JS you can `throw` everything, including true/false or a string or a number: but *JavaScript code also throws things without `throw`* (when you do things like trying to access properties on nulls) and there is a settled API for this (the `Error` object). So when you get around to catching, it's usually nice to be able to assume that those errors are `Error` objects. And since the `reject` for the promise will agglomerate in any errors from any of the above bugs, you generally want to only `throw` other errors, to make your `catch` statement have a simple, consistent logic.

Therefore although you **can** put an if-conditional in your `catch` and look for false errors, in which case the truth case is trivial,

```hs
Either (Either Error ()) ()
```

you will probably prefer the logic structure, at least for what comes **immediately** out of the authenticator, of a simpler boolean:

```hs
Either Error Bool
```

In fact the next level of authentication logic is probably to return some sort of `User` object containing the authenticated user, so that this becomes:

```hs
Either Error (Maybe User)
```

and this is more or less what I'd expect: return `null` in the case where the user is not defined, otherwise return `{user_id: <number>, permission_to_launch_missiles: <boolean>}`. I'd expect that the general case of not being logged in is salvageable, for example if we're in some sort of "demo to new clients" mode, and should not be mixed in with bugs where I accidentally called `object.doStuff()` when `object.doStuff` was `undefined`.

Now with that said, what you may want to do is to define a `NotLoggedIn` or `PermissionError` exception which derives from `Error`. Then in the things which really need it you want to write:

```js
function launchMissiles() {
    function actuallyLaunchThem() {
        // stub
    }
    return getAuth().then(auth => {
        if (auth === null) {
            throw new PermissionError('Cannot launch missiles without permission, cannot have permission if not logged in.');
        } else if (auth.permission_to_launch_missiles) {
            return actuallyLaunchThem();
        } else {
            throw new PermissionError(`User ${auth.user_id} does not have permission to launch the missiles.`);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Errors

Let's talk about errors.

There are two types of errors:

- expected errors
- unexpected errors
- off-by-one errors

### Expected Errors

Expected errors are states where the wrong thing happens but you know that it might, so you deal with it.

These are things like user input or server requests. You know the user might make a mistake or that the server might be down, so you write some checking code to make sure that the program asks for input again, or displays a message, or whatever other behavior is appropriate.

These are recoverable when handled. If left uhandled, they become unexpected errors.

### Unexpected Errors

Unexpected errors (bugs) are states where the wrong thing happens because the code is wrong. You know that they'll eventually happen, but there's no way to know where or how to deal with them because, by definition, they're unexpected.

These are things like syntax and logic errors. You may have a typo in your code, you may have called a function with the wrong parameters. These aren't typically recoverable.

## `try..catch`

Let's talk about `try..catch`.

In JavaScript, `throw` isn't commonly used. If you look around for examples in code they're going to be few and far between, and usually structured along the lines of

```
function example(param) {
  if (!Array.isArray(param) {
    throw new TypeError('"param" should be an array!');
  }
  ...
}
```

Because of this, `try..catch` blocks aren't all that common for control flow either. It's usually pretty easy to add some checks before calling methods to avoid expected errors.

JavaScript environments are pretty forgiving as well, so unexpected errors are often left uncaught as well.

`try..catch` doesn't have to be uncommon. There are some nice use cases, which are more common in languages such as Java and C#. Java and C# have the advantage of typed `catch` constructs, so that you can differentiate between expected and unexpected errors:

<sub>C#</sub>:

```
try
{
  var example = DoSomething();
}
catch (ExpectedException e)
{
  DoSomethingElse(e);
}
```

This example allows other unexpected exceptions to flow up and be handled elsewhere (such as by being logged and closing the program).

In JavaScript, this construct can be replicated via:

```
try {
  let example = doSomething();
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceOf ExpectedError) {
    DoSomethingElse(e);
  } else {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Not as elegant, which is part of the reason why it's uncommon.

## Functions

Let's talk about functions.

If you use the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), each class and function should serve a singular purpose.

For example `authenticate()` might authenticate a user.

This might be written as:

```
const user = authenticate();
if (user == null) {
  // keep doing stuff
} else {
  // handle expected error
}
```

Alternatively it might be written as:

```
try {
  const user = authenticate();
  // keep doing stuff
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceOf AuthenticationError) {
    // handle expected error
  } else {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Both are acceptible.

## Promises

Let's talk about promises.

Promises are an asynchronous form of `try..catch`. Calling `new Promise` or `Promise.resolve` starts your `try` code. Calling `throw` or `Promise.reject` sends you to the `catch` code.

```
Promise.resolve(value)   // try
  .then(doSomething)     // try
  .then(doSomethingElse) // try
  .catch(handleError)    // catch
```

If you have an asynchronous function to authenticate a user, you might write it as:

```
authenticate()
  .then((user) => {
    if (user == null) {
      // keep doing stuff
    } else {
      // handle expected error
    }
  });
```

Alternatively it might be written as:

```
authenticate()
  .then((user) => {
    // keep doing stuff
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    if (e instanceOf AuthenticationError) {
      // handle expected error
    } else {
      throw e;
    }
  });
```

Both are acceptible.

### Nesting

Let's talk about nesting.

`try..catch` can be nested. Your `authenticate()` method might internally have a `try..catch` block such as:

```
try {
  const credentials = requestCredentialsFromUser();
  const user = getUserFromServer(credentials);
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceOf CredentialsError) {
    // handle failure to request credentials
  } else if (e instanceOf ServerError) {
    // handle failure to get data from server
  } else {
    throw e; // no idea what happened
  }
}
```

Likewise promises can be nested. Your async `authenticate()` method might internally use promises:

```
requestCredentialsFromUser()
  .then(getUserFromServer)
  .catch((e) => {
    if (e instanceOf CredentialsError) {
      // handle failure to request credentials
    } else if (e instanceOf ServerError) {
      // handle failure to get data from server
    } else {
      throw e; // no idea what happened
    }
  });
```

## So what's the answer?

Ok, I think it's time for me to actually answer the question:

> Is a failure in authentication considered something you would reject a promise for?

The simplest answer I can give is that you should reject a promise anywhere you would otherwise want to `throw` an exception if it were synchronous code.

If your control flow is simpler by having a few `if` checks in your `then` statements, there's no need to reject a promise.

If your control flow is simpler by rejecting a promise and then checking for types of errors in your error handling code, then do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Handling a promise is ***more or less like*** "if" condition. It's up to you whether you want to "resolve" or "reject" if authentication failed.

Comment: promise is an asynchronous `try..catch`, not `if`.

Comment: @zzzBox so by that logic, you should use a Promise as a asynchronous `try...catch` and simply say that if you were able to complete and get a result, you should resolve regardless of the value that was received, otherwise you should reject?

Comment: @somethinghere, no, you've misconstrued my argument. `try { if (!doSomething()) throw whatever; doSomethingElse() } catch { ... }` is perfectly fine, but the construct that a `Promise` represents is the `try..catch` part, not the `if` part.

Comment: @zzzzBov I got that in all fairness :) I like the analogy. But my logic is simply that if `doSomething()` fails, then it will throw, but if not it could contain the value you need (your `if` above is slightly confusing as its _not_ part of your idea here :)). You should only reject if there is a reason to throw (in the analogy), so if the test failed. If the test succeeded you should always resolve, regardless of whether its value is positive, right?

Comment: @somethinghere, I've decided to write up an answer (assuming this stays open long enough), because comments are not enough for expressing my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the "reject" branch of a Promise to represent the "cancel" action of jQuery UI dialog boxes.  It seemed more natural than using the "resolve" branch, not least because there's often multiple "close" options on a dialog box.

Comment: Most purists I know would disagree with you.